# jquery enable :hover of div on other div mouseover

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseevent, mouseover

I need TOGGLE :hover action of specific div, but also when mouse cursor is over other DIV

```
  <div class="ms-thumb">
    <div class="ms-product-thumb">
        <div class="ms-thumb-hover">
            .ms-thumb-hover
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-thumb-desc">
        on this mouseover: make '.ms-thumb-hover' red!
    </div>
  </div>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
$('.ms-thumb-desc').hover(function(){
    $('.ms-thumb-hover').hover();
});
</script>
```

Here is Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u4a1z3d2/3/

Explain please why this jQuery action don't work?

Comment: you did not enable jquery in you jsfddle

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: FIDDLE UPDATEED... I need trigger on [css]:hover action of class '.ms-thumb-hover' div when the mouse is over '.ms-thumb-desc'

Comment: can you give me an explanation of why you would want to do this? All you want is to make one div red when hovering the other one. Why this does not work for you? Why you need to call hover of another div ? What is the point?

Comment: ok if don't know how do this.. thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot force an element state using jQuery since it's not a trusted event. You'll have to create a hover class and use toggleClass on the element

jQuery:

```
$('.ms-thumb-desc').hover(function(){
    $('.ms-thumb-hover').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

CSS:

```
.ms-thumb-hover:hover, .ms-thumb-hover.hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u4a1z3d2/6/

See [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events) for an explanation on trusted events.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, because it explain me that i must use toggleClass instead "hover()' as i thought

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please accept the answer so other users can see that your question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ms-thumb-desc').hover(function () {
    $('.ms-thumb-hover').css("font-size", "1.5em");
    $('.ms-thumb-hover').css("color", "red");
    }, function () {
    $('.ms-thumb-hover').css("color", "black");
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/u4a1z3d2/1/

Comment: hover action, not css change

Comment: @X9DESIGN what do you mean?

Comment: I need toggle :hover of '.ms-thumb-hover' div but when the mouse is over '.ms-thumb-desc'

Comment: @X9DESIGN why would you want to do that?

Comment: because .. i dont understand your question...
did you know how  do that or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [http://jsfiddle.net/u4a1z3d2/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/u4a1z3d2/2/)

```
$('.ms-thumb-desc').hover(function(){
    $('.ms-thumb-hover').css("background", "red");
}, function() {
    $('.ms-thumb-hover').css("background", "none");
});
```

and don't forget to add library in jsfiddle.

Comment: i dont write nothin about css change... read entire post, don't look only at the code

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with no JS at all by targeting the parent and then erasing on the children:

```
.ms-thumb:hover .ms-product-thumb {
    color: red;
}
.ms-thumb .ms-product-thumb:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u4a1z3d2/5/